# iOS Phonegap: disable auto-lock but allow turning off the screen

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm working with Phonegap and I'm trying to disable the auto-lock, but allow in the meantime the phone to turn off the screen. So the phone is not locked, but the screen appears off. This is in order to save battery and allow my application to continue its work.

Can this be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain that is not possible, even with the official Apple SDK.